# How can I find the part of string is in List in python

Tags: python

Let's say I have the following list

```
List = ['Apple', 'Banana', 'Orange', 'Grapes']
```

From this I want to search `Apple` I have to use the following code

```
if 'Apple' in List: 
    print "Found"
```

But I want to search the string which contains `'App'` what do I have to do?

I can use `For` loop and `if` statement combined.

```
for items in List: 
    if 'App' in items: 
        print "Found"
```

But is there any other way to do this process?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `map` + `any`:

```
lst = ['apple', 'banana']

if any(map(lambda x: 'app' in x.lower(), lst)):
    print "Found"
```

Slightly more pythonic:

```
lst = ['apple', 'banana']
if any(['app' in x.lower() for x in lst]):
    print "Found"
```

A slightly more optimized version using a generator (if the first element is "apple", it won't check the rest of the lst):

```
generator = ('app' in x.lower() for x in lst)
if any(generator):
    print "Found"
```

Comment: What is a generator? that syntax looks like a n-tuple to me.

Comment: @kpie: Start at [Iterators](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#iterators) in the tutorial, and read through the end of the chapter.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1756096/understanding-generators-in-python - essentially it's a lazy way of iterating over the list. Instead doing all the work immediately, it will only do work on the current element while iterating.

Comment: Not quite pythonic`any(['app' in x.lower() for x in list])` always creates a full list every time, also `list` is probably not a great name for a variable. `if any('app' in x.lower() for x in lst)` would be pythonic

Comment: Hey @PadraicCunningham, thanks for the feedback - changed the var name of `list`, for your suggested code, it's actually in the answer at the end.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(True in ["app" in k for k in ["apple","orange","grapes"]]):
    print("woot")
```

Is more or less readable but does the same thing.

you could even make it a one liner,

```
print "woot" if(True in ["app" in k for k in ["apple","orange","grapes"]]) else ""
```

Comment: Why make a list and then scan it for `True` instead of just using `any`?

Comment: No reason that I know of.

Answer (score 0):

If you're just looking for something more concise, the exact same logic can be written with a [comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) (in this case, a [generator expression](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#generator-expressions))
and the [`any`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any) function:

```
if any('App' in item for item in List):
    print "Found"
```

---

If it isn't obvious why this does almost the same thing as your existing code:

If you expand the comprehension to an explicit `for` statement, it looks like this:

```
for item in List:
    yield 'App' in item
```

Then, the `any` function iterates over each thing that got `yield`ed until one of them is true, or until it gets to the end and they were all false.

So, the only difference is that instead of printing `"Found"` once for each time something was found, it just prints it once and then stops looking.

---

If you want something more *efficient*, you'd need to change your data structure. But I doubt that's an issue when you've only got 4 things in `List`.